# C# Windows Form Application ListView: How do I force the ListView to not update?

Tags: c#

I know that you can forcibly refresh the ListView using the method `ListView.Refresh()`. However, how do I forcibly stop the ListView from updating its list every time I insert an object (for design purposes)?

Code:

```
string[] newData = { //Some strings };
ListViewItem newRow = new ListViewItem(newData);
listView1.Items.Add(newRow);
```

The above will insert a new row into my `listView1` and `listView` will automatically update its list and add that new item at the bottom-most row. **I want to prevent the automatic adding of data into my visual list, I want to only update the data on the click of a button I've provided**.

Comment: Please be specific.. `I forcibly stop the ListView from updating its list` and `for design purposes` what do you mean by this

Comment: @TheGeneral I've added some more details.

Comment: Why don't you just add your data to the array and only add it to the `Items` when you click the button?

Comment: @JohanP I can do that, but is it not possible with a direct update to ListView?

Comment: You can invoke `ListView.BeginUpdate()` when start updating the entries. When you are done, invoke `ListView.EndUpdate()`. This will make sure that no refreshes occurs during the update.

Comment: @JohanP Also, it is a little harder to track if items are deleted and inserted. I'd have to clear the `ListView` per that refresh button, wouldn't I?

Comment: DO NOT directly update the control.  Do as @JohanP suggests

Comment: @JohnB Could you elaborate why? I'm sorry if this sounds ignorant.

Comment: simply changing the data source is the cleanest approach.  it also keep a 'one source of truth' concerning the data being displayed

Comment: @JohnB I see. If I do so, upon deletion of a ListViewItem, it seems like the best approach to delete is to update both ListView and the data source simultaneously, right?

Comment: no - delete the item from the datasource then call the 'rebind'? or similar on the control - this refreshes the display control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you can do is create a class that will manage your state for you:

```
   public class ListViewStateHelper
    {
        private readonly ListView _listView;
        private readonly List<string> _items;
        public ListViewStateHelper(ListView listView)
        {
            _listView = listView;
            _items = new List<string>();
        }

        public void AddItem(string value)
        {
            _items.Add(value);
        }

        public void DeleteItem(string value)
        {
            _items.Remove(value);
        }

        public void Refresh()
        {
            _listView.Items.AddRange(_items.Select(i => new ListViewItem(i)).ToArray());
        }

    }
```

then create a global variable and initialize it

```
   private readonly ListViewStateHelper _stateHelper;
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        _stateHelper = new ListViewStateHelper(listView1);
    }
```

then have your event handlers call it:

```
private void add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _stateHelper.AddItem("a");
}

private void delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _stateHelper.DeleteItem("a");
}

private void refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _stateHelper.Refresh();
}
```

Or you can simply just create a global variable that will hold your datasource and work against it, then you don't need the state helper class.